# Have access 2 networks but both are still independent

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, dhcp

This is my setup:

```
    *House 1*      :   House 2**
          [C]      :      Device1
         /         :     /
[A]-----(B)--------:---(D)--Device2
         \         :     \
          Devices  :      Device 2
```

- [A] - modem router: internet source1 global, also is DHCP server
  (192.168.8.1)
- (B) - Router: used as extender (DHCP off)
- [C] - modem
  router: internet source2 closed, DHCP is off (192.168.3.1)
- (D) -
  Router: used as another extender, DHCP is off

What I do to access [C] internet through (D) by setting device gateway(192.168.3.1) and ip (192.168.3.106), and was able to get this to work but couldn't make it work now

Essentially what I want to achieve is to (D) to only have access to [C] internet but also be able to access a server on network [A]. Like access 2 networks via one cable and only House 2 having access to [C]

I have minimal knowledge on networking, and most of the routers in this setup have just basic functionality

Comment: Do they (primarily A and C) at least have the functionality of adding custom "static routes"? Did I understand it right that B and D are either in bridge mode or connected entirely through their LAN ports?

Comment: This will be difficult with just "basic functionality". Can you install something like OpenWRT on the router(s)?

Comment: @user1686 only router [A] has that feature, yes they are connected via lan ports and just turned off the dhcp server

Comment: @user1686 only C does not have static routes functionality